# How to compare a file changes since last action in github actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

In gitlab we have support for `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` and `CI_COMMIT_SHA`

Whereas in github we only have support for [GITHUB_REF](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables#default-environment-variables) which holds SHA of current commit that triggered this action.

My requirement is to find if a particular file changed since last Action execution

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860732/how-can-i-get-the-previous-commit-before-a-push-or-merge-in-github-action-workfl/61861763#61861763) may help you.

Comment: Thanks @peterevans that worked out for me

Comment: @RohitReddyAbbadi Were you able to get something implemented? I am trying to do the same thing (seems like there should be a utility), but not sure where to start. Is there anything you could share?

Comment: @JosephCarroll added my solution as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to solve this using event payload - [see push event payload](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push):

in `.github/workflows/release.yaml`

```yaml
name: release
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: deploy
      run: sh deploy.sh
      env:
        CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA: ${{ github.event.before }}
        CI_COMMIT_SHA: ${{ github.event.after }}
```

in `bin/deploy.sh`

```bash
HAS_DESIRED_CHANGES=`git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA | grep -E 'path/to/file1|path/to/dir2'`
echo $HAS_DESIRED_CHANGES
HAS_DESIRED_CHANGES=`echo ${#HAS_DESIRED_CHANGES}`

if ! [ $HAS_DESIRED_CHANGES -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Has desired changes, proceed performing necessary actions"
else
  echo "No desired changes. Skipping...."
fi
```