# Turborepo with 2 react apps and CircleCI CI/CD only run for changed app

Tags: reactjs, circleci, monorepo, turborepo

I'm using Turborepo for my monorepo project, i have 2 react apps. How can i configure Turborepo and CircleCI (repos are on Github) so if i make changes to one project that pipeline is not going to run for second project?

I know turbo is using hash algo to check if there is any changes to a project and then rebuild it.

I have tried looking here https://turborepo.org/docs/ci/circleci but does not explain the behavior of this.

Steps would be:

1. Make code change to Project 1
2. Commit changes of monorepo to Github
3. Github detects a commit and triggers CircleCI to run CI/CD
   So this part is what I'm not sure, if it triggers CI/CD it will trigger for the both projects right? And if so how can i prevent only for the one i have made changes?

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on such a solution for days now. There are two core-concepts in turborepo to achieve this:

- [Filtering workspaces](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/core-concepts/monorepos/filtering)
- Caching Buildoutputs and store the cache in the cloud (not what you're looking for)

So, you can `filter` your monorepo for a specific project, e.g:

```
pnpm turbo run build --filter='my-project...[HEAD^1]' --dry=json
```

-> This will look if the task `build` is needed to run for the project "my-project", comparing the current source with "HEAD^1". The option dry=json helps to just look if there would be a need to run "build" or not for "my-project".

You could filter a whole lot more, check the docs.

Now, what i have built on top of this:

1. A new job on the github workflow looks with the help of this filter command if a deployment of my graphql-server is needed and he will set the output of this decision as an artifact, to provide this information for later jobs (https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact)
2. My actual docker-build and deploy-to-fly-io jobs that run afterwards, will download this artifact and set a CONTINUE environment variable, depending if it should build + deploy or not.
3. Every job coming after that is having an `if: ${{ env.CONTINUE == 'true' }}` to skip them if no build/deploy is needed.

It could be much simpler if you can run your build/deploy job directly with the `turbo` cli, because then you can just combine your filter and the execution of the build - but that was not possible in my case.

If you need to "skip" jobs that are coming later in your workflow, it's harder thant it should, as github is not supporting ["abortion" of jobs](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/662).

For all the other commands like `lint`, `typecheck` and `test` -> just add an appropriate filter option to them and you will achieve that they only run on your "affected" workspaces/projects in your PR.

Ressources:

- https://dev.to/ngconf/deploying-nx-affected-apps-from-github-actions-54n4
- [How can I get the previous commit before a push or merge in GitHub Action workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860732/how-can-i-get-the-previous-commit-before-a-push-or-merge-in-github-action-workfl)
- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26313

Comment: You need to add a fetch-depth of 2 to your checkout step -> have a look into my other question here for proper filtering ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412706/correct-turborepo-filter-to-get-affected-workspaces-on-push-to-main