# Correct turborepo filter to get "affected" workspaces on push to main

Tags: git, github, github-actions, monorepo, turborepo

Whenever a pull request is merged to main branch, i want to run `turborepo run build` command only on the affected workspaces. With nx.dev, i just use the `${{ github.event.before }}` SHA to set as base and it just works: `npm run affected:build -- --base=${{ github.event.before }}`

How do i achieve this with turborepo? I have tried to get the `before` and `after` SHA from the github context and add a filter like this:

```
pnpm turbo run build --filter='[${{ github.event.before }}...${{ github.event.after }}]'
```

But it always says: `ERROR  run failed: failed to resolve packages to run: commit 247deb49c535ddc7cd0551fe3aa119697b497c00 does not exist` -> he means, the "before" SHA does not exist..

But when i look into the github context, there is even a "compare" URL, looking exact the same: `https://github.com/<path-to-my-repo>/compare/247deb49c535...8458601c6c8f`

And this compare show's me perfectly the changes that were made trough this PR. So, basically i think this should be correct, what am i missing?

Why is turborepo not working with the same compare?

Comment: Oh my - i was doing everything right, the missing piece is: add a `fetch-depth` of `2` to your `actions/checkout@v3` - then the before-SHA will exist :)